# Caching an array of elements using Redis

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, node-redis

I have a collection called `websites`. These websites are fetched when a user logs into his account.

### Database

#### Websites

```js
[
  {
    _id: ...,
    user: 1,
    title: 'My Website',
  },
  ...
]
```

### NodeJS

```js
async function getWebsites(user) {
  // Get the list of website ids
  let ids = await redis.json.get(`user:${user}:websites`);

  if (! ids) {
    ids = (await Website.find({ user }, { _id: 1 })).map(item => item._id);

    // if the length of ids is 0 then we store '0' to avoid repetitive queries.
    await redis.multi()
          .json.set(`user:${user}:websites`, ids.length > 0 ? ids : '0')
          .expire(18000)
          .exec();
  }

  if (ids === '0' || ids.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }

  // Get websites
  let pipeline = redis.multi();

  for (const id of ids) {
    pipeline.json.get(`website:${id}`);
  }

  const websites = await pipeline.exec();

  for (const website of websites) {
    // find absent websites, fetch them from database and store in redis (with expiration time)
  }

  return websites;
}

const websites = getWebsites(1);
```

## Problem:

This approach is in-efficient in my opinion but Redis' ebook does the same.
https://redis.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-8-building-a-simple-social-network/8-2-home-timeline/

Should i directly fetch the data from my database?

Answer (score 0):

using `multi()` is fine.

alternatively, you can store it as hash with `id` as key. you then can get item by hash key.